# How to make an object that can be assigned a value but can't be read?

Tags: c++

Output iterators can be assigned a value but their value can't be read. How can I make some object not readable but assignable like output iterators? I think that dereferencing an output iterator return an lvalue object that can be assigned a value. But, how can I get an lvalue object and not be able to read it?

Comment: is this just out of curiosity or do you have a specific use case for this?

Comment: @bolov just curiosity.

Comment: as to the output iterators you mean you can insert into them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can overload operator, including the assignment operator.

Here is an example where the `operator=` is overloaded to accept an integer:

```
class A
{
private:
    int val_;

public:
    A& operator=(int val)
    {
        val_ = val;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

My example is strictly academic. To be useful you need to have an actual use case for this.

> My question is how to make `*a = 3` a valid expression but `int b = *a` not a valid expression?

There are some ways. It all depends on the use case and what you want `*a` and `*a = 3` to do. One way is to have `operator*` return a class like the above:

```
class X
{
public:
    A operator*() const
    {
        return A{};
    }
}
```

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right, it can be confusing to novices. I've edited for the classic syntax.

Comment: I can assign some value to output iterators by dereferencing them then assigning. But I can't read what I dereferenced. My qustion is how to make "*a = 3" a valid expression but "int b = *a" not a valid expression?

Comment: probably the operator* should be public.